# glBlitFramebuffer & swizzle

Tags: opengl, blit

Is it possible to use glBlitFramebuffer to copy the alpha component from a read framebuffer with RGBA color attachment to a red component of draw framebuffer with R8 color attachment? If not, how would you do this?

Apparently the swizzle mask isn't used by glBlitFramebuffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this (without pulling the memory from the GPU back to the CPU) is with some form of rendering operation. A blit can't do it.

You can use a [compute shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader), if that's available. Just bind the source and destination images via [Image Load Store](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) and read/write to them based on the compute shader's invocation index.

However, it's not clear exactly what you hope to gain by doing this copy operation. If you only plan to read from the `GL_R8` texture as a bound texture/image, then all you need to do is create a [view texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/View_Texture) of the RGBA image. The reason to create a view of it is to be able to give the view a different [swizzle mask](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask). Simply swizzle the alpha into the red, and set green/blue/alpha to 0,0,1.

Obviously it won't be as efficient to access as a true `GL_R8` texture. But you won't have to execute a potentially expensive copy operation either.

Using GL 4.5 Direct State Access calls:

```
GLuint alpha_tex;
glCreateTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, &alpha_tex);
glTextureView​(alpha_tex, GL_TEXTURE_2D, rgba_tex, GL_RGBA8, 0, num_mipmaps(rgba_tex)​, 0, 1​)
GLint swizzleMask[] = {GL_ALPHA, GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE};
glTexureParameteriv(alpha_tex, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicol for you quick reply. Since I can't use too recent opengl, I am trying with a fragment shader, using different options: gl_FragColor = texture(samp, tc.xy);

This will take the current texture swizzle on the source, but doesn't take the swizzle of the dest. I suppose I need to do the dest swizzle mask in the shader: vec4(texture(samp, tc.xy).a) for ex.